# How to make a distance matrix like this image?

Tags: r

[what I am going for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TnpN.png)

```
dist(www, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)
n <- -dist(www, diag = TRUE, upper = FALSE )
```

With `dist()`, I could make only half of the table right. (All negative or all positive)

How do I make a distance matrix according to the distances given, in a way that it shows negative and positive values like in the image?

Is there a way I could make such a table instead of just importing a dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may multiply the lower triangle of the matrix by -1.

```
df <- head(mtcars)
mat <- as.matrix(dist(df, upper = TRUE))
mat[lower.tri(mat)] <- mat[lower.tri(mat)] * -1
mat

#                   Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout Valiant
#Mazda RX4            0.00000       0.61533     54.909         98.113            210.34  65.472
#Mazda RX4 Wag       -0.61533       0.00000     54.892         98.096            210.34  65.439
#Datsun 710         -54.90861     -54.89152      0.000        150.994            265.08 117.755
#Hornet 4 Drive     -98.11252     -98.09589   -150.994          0.000            121.03  33.551
#Hornet Sportabout -210.33744    -210.33585   -265.083       -121.030              0.00 152.124
#Valiant            -65.47177     -65.43922   -117.755        -33.551           -152.12   0.000
```

Answer (score 0):

We may also use `replace`

```
 replace(mat, lower.tri(mat), mat[lower.tri(mat)] * -1)
                     Mazda RX4 Mazda RX4 Wag Datsun 710 Hornet 4 Drive Hornet Sportabout   Valiant
Mazda RX4            0.0000000     0.6153251   54.90861       98.11252          210.3374  65.47177
Mazda RX4 Wag       -0.6153251     0.0000000   54.89152       98.09589          210.3359  65.43922
Datsun 710         -54.9086059   -54.8915169    0.00000      150.99352          265.0832 117.75470
Hornet 4 Drive     -98.1125212   -98.0958939 -150.99352        0.00000          121.0298  33.55087
Hornet Sportabout -210.3374396  -210.3358546 -265.08316     -121.02976            0.0000 152.12414
Valiant            -65.4717710   -65.4392224 -117.75470      -33.55087         -152.1241   0.00000
```

#### data

```
df <- head(mtcars, 6)
mat <- as.matrix(dist(df, upper = TRUE))
```